# Linux: create dynamic growing volume/container inside a regular file

Tags: linux, file-management, disk-image

I am looking for a software to create a resizeable (growing) mountable container inside a file. The concept is simple: I have a file-container, I mount this file container to a mount-point and then copy files into it. The container grows as long as it needs free space to store files inside itself. A good example is given at this article:

https://www.debian-administration.org/article/664/Creating_dynamic_volumes_with_loop_devices

But in the comments people are pointing that given approach is unsafe because it have unsolved issues with the limitations on the disk space: when a free space of underlying filesystem will end, any file operation could cause data corruption. So I'm seeking for a good reliable solution how to create such auto-resizeable containers.

Answers should mention how the solution manages to not corrupt anything when the underlying filesystem runs out of space.

It would be perfect if using this solution I could also encrypt the container-file contents with an arbitrary encryption algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

You should either use or derive from [TrueCrypt](http://truecrypt.sourceforge.net/) which allowed you to safely create a mountable, encrypted, volume optionally auto-sizing with a maximum size set. Never heard of anybody getting problems because it grew too much.

Note that the encryption is stated not to be 100% safe and work on it suspended.

Comment: I'm afraid I can't accept your answer because TrueCrypt is no longer supported by it's developers and what's more important for me - I having a lot of troubles compiling it on Ubuntu 14.04.1. Right now I'm stuck at "lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line" and this whole situation discourages me a bit from using it. Probably there is other open-source alternatives to this solution?

Comment: @user619271 there may be other OS solutions but if their crypo is any good someone stamps fast.